# How do I serve my React app using only client-side?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, docker-compose, cors, fastapi

I am completely new to Docker, and have gone through a few tutorials about creating a FastAPI image. It is my goal to understand how to set up a single-page-app using React, FastAPI, and Docker by the end of this project.

I got stuck creating the client side. I wanted to use Webpack and Babel to transpile my code, but since I didn't use create-react-app I am missing a way to host my client app. My previous way of doing it would be to serve static files using Express, but since this uses multiple Docker images I am not sure of the solution.

```
client
  -app
    ->dist
    ->src
  -node_modules
  -.babelrc
  -.dockerignore
  -Dockerfile
  -package-lock.json
  -package.json 
  -webpack.config.js
server
.gitignore
docker-compose.yaml
```

---

From what I have been seeing in tutorials and blogs, CORSMiddleware may be a potential solution for routing JS code from the browser to FastAPI, but would this allow for serving content from my app? I greatly appreciate any correction of my understanding or pointing me in the right direction for researching this. :)

Comment: CORS is for letting your frontend (_after_ being served) make requests to the API through Javascript - it's not relevant to the initial serving of the client application. If you want to serve that through FastAPI, you can use the static file support with the pre-built dist files from your builder: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Will serving static files from the backend be possible if it is separated by Docker images?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need multiple docker images in that case, since both the API and the frontend application would be served by the FastAPI image.